# Make a window shortcut permanent

Tags: shortcut-keys, kubuntu, kde, window, focus

I want to be able to always make the terminal window pop-up with focus with the same keyboard shortcut.

I've found so far that if I right-click the window and go to `More Actions > Window Shortcuts`, it does exactly what I want.

The problem is, the shortcut doesn't survive the window close. I would like to find a way to make this permanent, even after reboot.

Please note that I'm not asking for a global keyboard shortcut to open the window, that is already correctly configured, I only want to give the focus to the window as the window shortcut does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Permanent**

Right click the window border > More actions > Special Window/Application Settings > Arrangement & Access tab

or/and

KDE System Settings > Window Behavior > Window Rules

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! I had even found that menu but I didn't know what the options were, I actually still have no idea what force actually means in this context, some clarification would be great but thanks a lot anyways! :)

Comment: The KDE has the UserBase wiki: http://userbase.kde.org/. The KWin Rules UserBase page: http://userbase.kde.org/KWin_Rules and the Attributes : http://userbase.kde.org/KWin_Rules_Window_Attributes . As a pdf file: http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/windowspecific/windowspecific.pdf